# Simple File Downloader in Cocoa [Help]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to create a Simple single File Downloader in cocoa.. I am using VMWARE with MAC OS 10.5 image

Here is the code of main.m, but it is not working. Not showing any error or warning message nor downloading any file.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.mig33.com/wap2/v4_50/24x24/mig33v45.jar";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *dataPath = @"~/Desktop/mig33v45.jar"; 
    [data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

Where i am doing wrong? I am new in cocoa programing.

-Thanks
-regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need an NSAutoreleasePool and you don't need the NSApplicationMain call.

this works:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.mig33.com/wap2/v4_50/24x24/mig33v45.jar";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *dataPath = [@"~/Desktop/mig33v45.jar" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]; 
    [data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works now.. I need to understand about [pool drain]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
NSString *dataPath = [@"/Desktop/mig33v45.jar" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```